# How to add GET and remove

Tags: php

I have more GET variables. I want the variables to be added after clicking. And after clicking again I want them to be removed from GET. I am a beginner and I don't know how to do it.

```
<?php
$tab_array['name1']=1;
$tab_array['name2']=2;
$tab_array['name3']=3;
$tab_array['name4']=4;

$url=$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING];

if(!empty($url)){
    $url="&".$url;
}
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <?php
    foreach($tab_array as $key => $val){
        ?>
        <a href="?<?php echo $key;?>=<?php echo $val;?><?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $key;?></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Someone will help?

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please elaborate on what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: For me its clear, hold my beer :)

Answer (score -1):

## Code

```
<?php
$tab_array['name1']=1;
$tab_array['name2']=2;
$tab_array['name3']=3;
$tab_array['name4']=4;

$url='?'; // this will call the current url

// $_GET is the array your submitted data will be strored in - initially empty []

?>

<form method='GET'><!-- you actually don't need a form, since only input, textarea, etc get submitted -->
<?php

// save current state, so you can modify it for every possible click
$current_get = $_GET;

foreach($tab_array as $key => $value) {
    $new_get = $current_get;

    // check if the current key is already in your set ($new_get)

    if (array_key_exists($key, $new_get)) { // it is, so remove
        unset($new_get[$key]);
    } else { // it is not, so add
        $new_get[$key] = $value;
    }

    // build your query_string (from $new_get array)
    $query_string = http_build_query($new_get);

    // you can use variables in string when its encapsulated in double quotes: "text $var"
    echo "<a href='$url$query_string'>$key</a>";

    // more readable:
    // echo "<a href='{$url}{$query_string}'>{$key}</a>";

    // not need but looks better :P
    echo '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
</form>
```

## A little more

there is a shortcut for `<php echo $var ?>` which is just `<?= $var ?>`

## Links

[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

[unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

[http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)